# a c program that converts decimal to 36 different bases but there's a simple error

Tags: c, decimal

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

long int input;
long int base, exponent;

void convert(long int x,long int y)
{
    input = x;
    base = y;

    while (input > 0){
        exponent = floor(log(input)/log(base));
        input = input - pow(base, exponent);
    }
}

int main(void){
    scanf("%d", &input);
    scanf("%d", &base);
    convert(input, base);
}
```

I was trying to compile the code above to see if I can convert decimal into different bases, but I get the following error:

```
assignment2.c(14): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
```

I have been struggling for hours, but I have no idea what this is referring to. How can I fix this?

EDIT: this is the whole message

```
1>------ Build started: Project: assignment2, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 2012-04-27 오후 5:45:10.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\assignment2.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  assignment2.c
1>c:\users\조화수\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\assignment2\assignment2\assignment2.c(14): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
1>  assign2.c
1>c:\users\조화수\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\assignment2\assignment2\assign2.c(13): warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'long', possible loss of data
1>c:\users\조화수\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\assignment2\assignment2\assign2.c(14): warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'long', possible loss of data
1>c:\users\조화수\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\assignment2\assignment2\assign2.c(19): warning C4996: 'scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using scanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\stdio.h(304) : see declaration of 'scanf'
1>c:\users\조화수\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\assignment2\assignment2\assign2.c(20): warning C4996: 'scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using scanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\stdio.h(304) : see declaration of 'scanf'
1>  Generating Code...
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:02.98
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Are you sure you posted the code that matches that error message? (Or the error message that matches this code?)

Comment: If this is indeed the entire source file, I would start by renaming some variables, just in case I had hit on one that was already defined as a macro.

Comment: you scanf the input and base then pass and again assign the value of global variable  input and base to input and base don't you create a conflict

Comment: `cat -n assignment2.c`, should probably tag it homework too.

Comment: Which line is line 14? Also, you are probably supposed to solve the problem with integer operations like `%` and `/` instead of the floating point function from `math.h`

Comment: @Mat yes i have. i've tested it countless times because i didn't believe it as well.

Comment: [it compiles fine](http://ideone.com/sIaGT). The error is somewhere else.

Comment: The code you posted compiles without errors for me (using a different compiler, though). Hwa Soo Cho, can you please confirm (as Mat asked) that you posted the exact same code that failed, and the exact same error message as you got? Is line 14 the one that begins `input = input -`?

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio **C** compiler is buggy.

Comment: i have no idea what -lm or cat -n assignment2.c are. i'm super new to programming. i'm really sorry if i can't provide any further help..

Comment: (The easiest way to do the check is probably to copy-and-paste the text from this SO question into a new file and verify that it still fails. If it doesn't, compare the old and new files.)

Comment: Incidentally, (1) I agree with sth that whoever set you this assignment was probably hoping you'd do it using integer division and modulus operations, (2) you're not actually reporting the results of your conversion, and (3) you might want to consider what happens if you ask it to convert, let's say, 1000100 to base 10.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan yes that is the line 14. i have made sure that that is the exact code and error. the following is the whole message from visual studio 2010:

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan i have tried to think it through using modulus, but in the end this was the best i could come up with. it's just a thought process i use to convert mathematically in real life. if there's a better way is it possible to ask for hints?

Comment: I have copied-and-pasted your code into a new C file in Visual Studio 2010 and it compiles with no errors (but with a few warnings unrelated to what you're reporting here). If I build it as C++ instead of as C, I get errors but again they're unrelated to what you report here (see mihai's answer).

Comment: Hint: The usual way to do this sort of conversion is to figure out the *last* digit first.

Comment: looks like it does work in other compiler.. that's really strange.. anyways thanks for the help guys! this is my first post here and i'm already loving your help. thanks!!

Comment: Yea, very strange. I tested this in VS2010 as well and not getting the same error. Instead the compiler still complains about ambiguous overloads.

Comment: The compiler output says that you are compiling two files, `assignment2.c` and `assign2.c`. The warnings for `assign2.c` match the code you posted. The error you ask about is in the other file, `assignment2.c`.

Comment: that was actually the problem. sorry guys i'm really new to this so i did not know what was going on! but thanks for the tips for future reference

Comment: Strange, it compiles with VS2010.

Comment: @sth etc. are probably right. Outputting a number base 36 would require 36 unique symbols which, strangely, is the same count as members in ASCII ["0".."9"]+["A".."Z"].

Comment: Replace `exponent = floor(log(input)/log(base));` with `exponent = round(log(input)/log(base));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pow` and `log` expect double or float. With a cast it works for me:

```
exponent = floor(log((double)input)/log((double)base));
input = input - pow((double)base, (double)exponent);
```

Initially I got an error stating that the compiler couldn't resolve an ambiguity between various oveloads (on VS 2008)

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary in C.

Comment: You're right...I had the file renamed to `.c` and there's no error. Why does this happen though?

Comment: Because C++ supports overloading, where you have different versions of a function that will be called depending on the types of the arguments you pass, and this feature is used by some of its mathematical functions. C++ has multiple different versions of `log`. C doesn't support overloaded functions and has only one version of `log`. (The very latest version of the C standard defines facilities for doing something a bit like this in C, but Microsoft's compiler doesn't support the very latest version of the C standard, or even the version before that, and probably never will.)

Answer (score 0):

how is it my friend :)?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int CB, DB;
 void base(void)
 {
   int adad2[100], i=-1,j;
   char adad1[100], ch;
   long int num1=0, num2=0;

   printf("Enter your num: ");
   scanf("%c", &ch);

   do
     {
       i++;
       scanf("%c", &adad1[i]);
     } while(adad1[i]!='\n');

   j=i-1;
   for(i=j;i>=0;i--)
     { //converts the base to 10.                                                                                                                                 
       if(adad1[i]<='9'&& adad1[i]>='0')
     {
       num1+=((long int)pow((float)CB,(j-i)))*(((int)adad1[i])-48);  //converting ascii code to num                                         
     }
       else if(adad1[i]<='Z'&&adad1[i]>='A')
     {
       num1+=((long int)pow((float)CB,(j-i)))*(((int)adad1[i])-55);
     }
       else if(adad1[i]<='z'&&adad1[i]>='a')
     {
       num1+=((long int)pow((float)CB,(j-i)))*(((int)adad1[i])-87);
     }
     }

   i=0;
   while(num1>=DB)
     { //converts the base to b. (START)                                                                                                                             
       adad2[i]=num1%DB;
       i++;
       num1/=DB;
     }

   adad2[i]=num1; //converts the base to b. (END)                                                                                                                                
   printf("\nResult: \n");

   for(;i>=0;i--)
     { //prints the result.                                                                                                                                          
       if(adad2[i]<=9&&adad2[i]>=0){
     printf("%d",adad2[i]);
       }

       else if(adad2[i]>=10&&adad2[i]<=35){
     printf("%c",(char)(adad2[i]+55));
       }
     }
 }

 void main(void)
 {
   printf("Guide: You must enter \"Current Base & Desired Base\" between 2 adn 32...");
   printf("\nEnter current base: ");
   scanf("%d", &CB);

   printf("\nEnter desired base: ");
   scanf("%d", &DB);

   base();
   getchar();
   printf("\n");

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

including fraction part in the previous code

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
      int rem,m=0,i,n;
      int a[100],base;
      float num,t,j;
      scanf("%f%d",&num,&base);
      n=(int)num;
      t=num-n;
      j=1.0/base;
      while(n){
               rem=n%base;
               if(rem<10)
               a[m++]=rem+'0';
               else
               a[m++]='A'+rem-10;
               n/=base;
      }
      while(m--)
      printf("%c",a[m]);
      printf(".");
      m=0;
      while(t>0.00001){
                       rem=0;
                        if(t>j)
                        {for(i=1;(j*i)<t;i++);
                        rem=i-1;}
                        if(rem==0)
                        a[m++]=0;
                        else if(rem<10)
                        a[m++]=rem+'0';
                        else
                        a[m++]='A'+rem-10;                        
                        t-=(j*rem);
                        j/=base;
      }
      for(i=0;i<m;i++)
      printf("%c",a[i]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**try this if you want to convert from decimal to any base upto 36**

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
      int n,rem,m=0,i;
      int a[100],base;
      scanf("%d%d",&n,&base);
      while(n){
               rem=n%base;
               if(rem<10)
               a[m++]=rem+'0';
               else
               a[m++]='A'+rem-10;
               n/=base;
      }
      while(m--)
      printf("%c",a[m]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! have added the code for fraction part in the new code.